# Access to Local Azure WCF Service from Windows Phone 8 Emulator

Tags: wcf, azure, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have a big problem with the Windows Phone 8 Emulator.

First I have an Azure project ,I have a WebRole this webrole expose some DomainServices (RIA Services) .

I exposed this DomainServices like SOAP, with others Apps like Windows 8 metro style or WPF app clients this services work fine.

But I trying to consume this services with Windows Phone 8 Emulator and I can't do that!.

I followed this article: [How to connect to a local web service from the Windows Phone 8 emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

I need to be more specific:

I have a website in a webRole of Windows Azure Project.

This website has a DomainServices (RIA Services) because I have a Silverlight Application inside.
I exposed this services with this.

```
 <domainServices>
  <endpoints>
    <add name="Soap" type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.SoapXmlEndpointFactory,
         Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, 
         Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </endpoints>
</domainServices>
```

I can consume this services with other apps. Windows metro Style and WPF and this services work fine.

Now, I want to develop a new application for Windows Phone 8 . But I need to consume this services.

In my local machine , I trying to connect this services with the emulator so, I researching and I found the emulator is a Virtual Machine and I need to configure IIS Express. 
I followed this article [How to connect to a local web service from the Windows Phone 8 emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

But I can't connect my Services hosted in the webRole with Windows Phone 8 Emulator.

This is the structure of my Website Project:
[image: Project Structure]

This the configuration of my WebRole Called LandingPage this web role has the services.
[image]

This the configuration of IIS Express inside of Applicationhost.config.

```
 <site name="LandingPage" id="2">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="E:\AnimesideFinal\AnimesideWebsite\LandingPage" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:24939:localhost" />
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:24939:192.168.2.114" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

This is the applications running in IIS Express is different of the Article.
[image]

Finally this is the Config of the service in the Windows Phone 8 emulator.

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_AuthenticationServiceSoap" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://192.168.2.114/Services/LandingPage-Services-AuthenticationService.svc/Soap"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_AuthenticationServiceSoap"
            contract="AuthService.AuthenticationServiceSoap" name="BasicHttpBinding_AuthenticationServiceSoap" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I followed all Steps of the article without results . I think something is wrong because I need to run my project from the Azure proj and in the properties of that exist the option to use IIS express or IIS web server.
[image]

And this is the error of Windows Phone Emulator.

{System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClasse.b__d(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result)
   at AnimesideWP7.AuthService.AuthenticationServiceSoapClient.AuthenticationServiceSoapClientChannel.EndLogin(IAsyncResult result)
   at AnimesideWP7.AuthService.AuthenticationServiceSoapClient.AnimesideWP7.AuthService.AuthenticationServiceSoap.EndLogin(IAsyncResult result)
   at AnimesideWP7.AuthService.AuthenticationServiceSoapClient.OnEndLogin(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult result)}

Thank you for your help .

Regards.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Is there any error or can't you get response or what? Be more specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing Azure Emulator from Windows Phone 8 Device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778456/accessing-azure-emulator-from-windows-phone-8-device)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the iis express solution section

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: If you can please explain what is happening to cause the issue and how it can be solved.