# Acces Azuresite from other device

Tags: azure

I develop an Azuresite on my computer and debug it on my local machine. I want to test the site on mobile devices too, but I can't access the page from one of my testphones. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is this a Windows Azure Web Site or a Cloud Service Web Role?  Also, when you run it locally is it hosted in IIS, IIS Express or Visual Studio Development Server?

Comment: IIS Express and it is a Cloud Service Web Role I think.

Comment: So the VS solution has a Cloud project in it with a web role that points to a web project, correct?  When you start it up the Azure emulator is also started?

Comment: Jep the Azure emulator starts normally.

Comment: Check out this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778456/debug-windows-phone-8-application-communication-with-a-cloud-service-running-on/18314935#18314935