# Connect asp.net core running docker on linux to Azure Storage Emulator running on Windows host

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, azure-storage

I'm developing a few microservices in asp.net core 2.1. Some of my services use Azure Storage. They are all hosted in Linux containers using Docker and all is well with that. I realize it would be possible to containarize the storage emulator but this is not what I want, I want to connect to the host running it.

My question boils down to; How do I connect my apps to the storage emulator running on my desktop(the host)?

Thanks!

Comment: Was the answer helpful to you ?

Comment: @AdamSmith-MSFT Thanks for the answer. I will check out Azurite but it doesn't quite answer my question. My issue presists even with Azurite. I will upvote but I cannot accept it as an answer. Sorry and thanks again. :)

Comment: I'd recommend checking  this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778456/accessing-azure-emulator-from-another-device 
I have not personally tried this solution, but the concept may help you connect your apps to a specific host. Let me know if this gets you closer to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately The storage emulator is not a scalable storage service and does not support a large number of concurrent clients.So it might not work for your desired scenario. It is also meant to act and work locally on a machine, not on a network based env(Connecting to the host hosting the emulator). I'd recommend checking this [**link**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator#differences-between-the-storage-emulator-and-azure-storage) which showcases the differences between the Azure storage and the Emulator capabilities.

Since you mentioned that your clients run on Linux, I'd recommend using [**Azurite**](https://github.com/azure/azurite), the equivalent of Azure Emulator for Linux, it also runs in Docker. So my suggestion would be to run multiple instances locally and test the app, or use a trial credit offered by Azure to see if it's the best fit.